# How to properly install Ubuntu to an Aspire E5 laptop?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, fglrx, acer

I have an Acer Aspire E5-551G-83LH laptop with the following specification:

- AMD Quad-Core Processor A8-7100 (that is an APU)
- AMD Radeon R7 M265 with 2 GB Dedicated VRAM
- 4 GB DDR3 L Memory

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit). What I have done already:

- Installed fglrx from the Software Center that solved display/resolution problems.
- Installed a kernel update that fixed the touchpad, so I can move the cursor and click now.
- I tried to install a fresh driver (fglrx) from AMD website but it fails during installation.

I still have the following problems that are really serious ones for me:

- Battery time is about 3-4 hours when I just run a browser with one tab and even in idle. Benchmarks tell me that I should have 9-10 but at least 7 hours.
- In system settings Ubuntu see only 3 BiB RAM.
- For graphics it tells me that I have "KV SPECTRE SL MOBILE 19W (1318)". What is this?
- When I turn on the laptop I get error messages before Ubuntu starts to load, and during shutdown the Ubuntu logout screen becomes noisy. I smell GPU driver problems here.
- Every few minutes the display makes a tiny blink.

I'm really surprised about all these problems. Usually I just install Ubuntu and have nothing to configure. Does Ubuntu have problems with Acer or AMD products?

Comment: Have you managed to solve the remaining problems in the meantime somehow? I think about buying an E5-551-81YH which is very similar to what you have. I would like to know what the HW support on Ubuntu 15.04 is for this machine.

Comment: @Kozuch I don't use Ubuntu at the moment, but I will instal it because the Win 8.1 they recommend is simply not that good (even with its drivers). The battery problem is solved, I just had to turn off the Wi-Fi and the Bluetooth. The video card's driver works fine, I didn't tested it under heavy load but it is usable so you can install an older driver that works with the latest kernel so your touchpad will work too. Maybe in the future there will be better drivers, but with a little experimenting you can create a proper environment.

Comment: I have the exactly same problems with Acer Aspire E5-551G-T0KC. It has the A10-7300 + R7 M265. Battery life is 3 hours, instead of 7 hours. Laptop gets hot quickly. 6.7 GiB memory instead of 8 GiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve most of the problems by the following ultimate solution:

**Install Ubuntu 15.04 or later**

Looks like that the touchpad and graphics problems are all solved by simply installing a newer version. The system still only see 3 GiB and the battery life seems to be a bit worse then what Windows offers but other than that, everything works fine.

Comment: have you had success in recent versions too? It would be good to know there was a supported Ubuntu fellow sufferers could upgrade to...

Comment: @Zanna I currently run 16.04 LTS and it works fine. The only problem that still remains is the 3Gib of RAM, but I have a feeling that the missing 1Gib might be used by the GPU.